# Serialization problem

Tags: c#, serialization

We save and read files by (de) serializing a class named "DocumentClass".
All was working well, untill we added 2 more fields to the documentclass. (We think that's the problem)

When we now try to open files that were serialized by the previous edition, we get an error.

System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'.
   at SoftwareProject.Componenten.Bestand.DocumentClass.d(String A_0)
   at de..ctor(String A_0)
   at g.a(String A_0)

The method generating the error is the method "Read". (DocumentClass.d() is the obfuscated name )

But things get weirder: when we open the file in VS debug mode, no error is generated, but all fields in the documentclass are 0 or null ???

We are lost here ... please help ...
We've added the  [OptionalField] attribute to the new fields, but that doesn't help ..

Why are all values null in debug mode ??
And where is the runtime error coming from ? How can we debug it ?

Thanks in advance!!

```
public static DocumentClass Read(string fullFilePath)
{

     DocumentClass c = new DocumentClass();
     Stream s = File.OpenRead(fullFilePath);
     BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
     //b.AssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;
     b.Binder = new MyCustomBinder(); 

     try
     {
      c = (DocumentClass)b.Deserialize(s);
     }
     catch( Exception exc )
     {
      s.Close();
      throw exc;
     }
     finally
     {
      s.Close();
     }
     return c;
        }


        public class MyCustomBinder : SerializationBinder {

     public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName) {
      Type tyType = null;
      string sShortAssemblyName = assemblyName.Split(',')[0];
      Assembly[] ayAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
      if (sShortAssemblyName.ToLower() == "debugAssemblyName")
      {
       sShortAssemblyName = "AppAssemblyName";
      }
      foreach (Assembly ayAssembly in ayAssemblies) {
       if (sShortAssemblyName == ayAssembly.FullName.Split(',')[0]) {
        tyType = ayAssembly.GetType(typeName);
        break;
       }
      }
      return tyType;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using `BinaryFormatter`? This serializer is notoriously brittle, since it (by default) includes the field-name in the stream; this impacts obfuscation [particularly badly](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/obfuscation-serialization-and.html). Presumably the obfuscator is now choosing new named for the fields (perhaps at random, perhaps due to the new fields), and so it can't deserialize correctly.

A few options:

- don't obfuscate the DTO
- implement `ISerializable` so the field names don't matter
- use a serializer that doesn't care about field names

I'd personally opt for the latter, but I'm a bit biased ;-p I know of people using [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) with obfuscated classes; the data only includes numeric markers, so the meaning isn't really exposed (except of course, by inspection of the data - post codes etc, but that is the job of encryption).

Answer (score 1):

.Net has something called "Version Tolerant Serialization" which most likely solves this issue ;)

You should check out this easy to understand example on object serialization:

http://programming.flashadventures.com/c-sharp/writing-objects-to-files-serialization/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [Custom Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675%28VS.80%29.aspx)